# Make a dynamic table with updated number values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to make a dynamic table with only html and js. So far I've created it to the point that when a name and number is entered, the table creates a new row with the inputed name and number. However, I'd like to make it so that if the same name but different number is entered, the row values change.

For example, if I enter `'Bob'` and `10`, the table will create a new row outputting `'Bob'` and `10`.
But if if enter `'Bob'` and `20`, the table row values will update to `'Bob'` and `30` (10 + 20). I would also like the row to delete itself if the number value reaches 0, for example if I enter `'Bob'` and `-10`, the values would be `'Bob'` and `0` and the row would delete itself.

```js
function createRows() {
  var inputName = document.getElementById("name").value;

  var inputStock = document.getElementById("stock").value;

  var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  var newRow = tableRef.insertRow();

  var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

  var newText = document.createTextNode(inputName);
  var newText2 = document.createTextNode(inputStock);

  newCell.appendChild(newText);
  newCell2.appendChild(newText2);
}
```

```html
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type name..." id="name">
<label for="stock">Stock</label>
<input type="number" placeholder="Type number..." id="stock">
<button type="button" onclick="createRows();">Get Value</button>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">Name</th>
      <th colspan="1">Stock</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `createRows` is called you'll have to go through all the rows to see if there is already an entry with that name and if it is, edit/delete it, if there isn't one, create a new entry.

Here is an example:

```js
function createRows() {
  var inputName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var inputStock = document.getElementById("stock").value;
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');

  var existingRow = Array.from(table.rows).find(row => row.cells[0].textContent === inputName);
  if (existingRow) {
    var newValue = parseInt(existingRow.cells[1].textContent) + parseInt(inputStock);
    if (newValue === 0) {
      existingRow.remove();
    } else {
      existingRow.cells[1].textContent = newValue;
    }
  } else {
    var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    var newRow = tableRef.insertRow();

    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

    var newText = document.createTextNode(inputName);
    var newText2 = document.createTextNode(inputStock);

    newCell.appendChild(newText);
    newCell2.appendChild(newText2);
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type name..." id="name">
<label for="stock">Stock</label>
<input type="number" placeholder="Type number..." id="stock">
<button type="button" onclick="createRows();">Get Value</button>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">Name</th>
      <th colspan="1">Stock</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are using O(n) time complexity for each update which I think is not optimal... can't we use a dictionary to store the key as string and value as existingrow.

Comment: @Titus How are you using `row.cells[0]` when creating an array from `table.rows`? I could not find any documentation for the `.cells` property on MDN.

Comment: @ElijahLee [Here is the documentation for `HTMLTableRowElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) in the **Properties** section you'll see it has a **cells** property.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to store key-value pairs where the key will be a string and the value will be an integer/float.

```
var dict = { key1 : value1 , 
             key2 : value2 , 
             .... 
           };
```

for each new key use:

```
dict[new_key] = new_value;
```

if the key is already present, then:

```
dict.key = dict[key] + new_value;
```

Then to show all key-value pairs in the table, Iterate over the dictionary.

```
for(var key in dict) {
   console.log(key + " : " + dict[key]);
}
```